# What can I use for plural-you? Should I use "you all"?

Tags: phrasal-verbs, personal-pronouns

It used to be the case that for the second person singular we would use "thou" and for second person plural we would use "you". These days, the "thou"s have been replaced with "you" except perhaps in the Southern USA.

Now, what if I want to emphasize that I'm addressing the plural rather than the singular? e.g. when talking to a person who's also representing a group? Would it sound super-weird if I said: "Pleased to make you all's acquaintance" instead of "Pleased to make your acquaintance"? Is there another way to say that?

Edit: The register of this phrase would be somewhat informal, almost tongue-in-cheek, within a formal encounter with the representative of the group.

Comment: It would sound super-weird. But then so would 'I'm pleased to meet you all' when talking to one person, no matter how many others they were representing.

Comment: In some places, "Pleased to make you all's acquaintance" would be OK.  Some places they have *youse* for you-plural.  But do not assume either of these in general.

Comment: The context can help: "Hello *everyone*. Pleased to make *your* acquaintance."

Comment: See https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/361217/youse-as-a-plural-second-person-pronoun regarding *youse as a plural second person pronoun*

Comment: @Lawrence: They're not in the room. Just one of them is. You've made the acquaintance of the company.

Comment: @einpoklum In that case, you're not making their (*plural*) acquaintance. You're making contact with the group as a singular entity through one of their representatives.

Comment: @GEdgar Are there really places where they say "you all", rather than "y'all"?

Comment: Please provide information about the register you are looking for. A formal greeting? Informal? Locale? What sounds super-weird in one context will sound completely natural in another.

Comment: @MetaEd: Edited that in.

Comment: I suppose that if "yawl" doesn't work you could say "ketch".  Not quite the same, but close.

Comment: @HotLicks: ketch?

Comment: @Barmar - Actually wouldn’t it be ***all y’alls*** for the plural?

Comment: @einpoklum Ketch was a joke.  A yawl is a kind of sailboat, and a ketch is a kind of sailboat.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, there are some regions where people say "you all" (or more commonly the contraction "y'all") or "youse", but they're not considered standard English. I don't think there's a single word for the plural "you", but you can say "all of you" to emphasize that you're addressing a group.

> I'm very please to meet all of you.

Answer (score 1):

**You would make changes elsewhere in the sentence.**

In the example you provided there are a few options:

> - Pleased to make your acquaintance**s**.
> - Pleased to make **all of your** acquaintance**s**.

These are clues that you mean more than one person.

To add to the commenters, *yinz* is another informal second person plural to accompany *youse* and *y'all*.